# Exception thrown when installing Logback-demo

Tags: java, logback

I'm just trying to install Logback-demo, using maven to package the files and run the demo for the first time, but I keep getting these weird java exception messages:

```
10:12:03.103 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  ch.qos.logback.demo.LoggingTask - Howdydy-diddly-ho - 8499
java.lang.Exception: e
    at ch.qos.logback.demo.LoggingTask.run(LoggingTask.java:28) [classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_65]
10:12:03,104 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Elapsed period: Thu May 21 10:11:03 PDT 2015
10:12:03,104 |-INFO in c.q.l.co.rolling.helper.RenameUtil - Renaming file [logFile.log] to [logFile.log4499498230724.tmp]
10:12:03,105 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.Compressor - ZIP compressing [logFile.log4499498230724.tmp] as [logFile.2015-05-21_10-11.log.zip]
```

this message will repeat over and over again for hours. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/demo/LoggingTask.java#L26), this seems normal:

```
public class LoggingTask implements Runnable {
  // ... 
  public void run() {
    if(i % 100 == 99) {
      logger.info(HOWDY_MARKER, msg + " - " + (i++), new Exception("e"));
    } else {
      logger.trace("x {]", i++);
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that no exception is thrown here, it's only logged.